# How to choose types for a function prototype?

Tags: c, function, refactoring

If I have a a data structure like a matrix or a tree, and I want to factor out a for loop from a very large function where the above variable is included, how should the call look like? I tried the following but I get a segmentation fault.

```
void write_command(int w, char *argv[], char *string[]) {
    char *dest;

    for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
        dest = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(argv[r]) + 1);
        *dest = '0';
        strcpy(dest, argv[r]);
        string[w][r] = *dest;
        free(dest);
    }
}
```

I think you see what I'm trying to do but how should I declare the variables? I get segfault at `string[w][r] = *dest;`.

I don't think you want to see what I'm refactoring but it is the biggest and most unreadable function ever.

```
static int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
    const char *cp;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    struct command structcommand[15];
    char **argv = 0;
    int argc = 1;
    bool pipe = false;
    char *string[z][z];
    char *pString3[40];
    char *pString2[40];
    int n = 0;
    char **ptr1;
    char string1[z];
    bool keep = false;
    char *pString1[z];
    char *pString[z];
    *pString1 = "\0";
    *pString = "\0";
    char *temp = {'\0'};
    int w = 0;
    bool b = false;
    int j = 0;
    int i;
    int p = 0;
    char **ptr;
    char *tmpchar;
    char *cmdtmp;
    bool b1 = false;
    char *dest;
    int y = 0;
    i = 0;
    int h = 0;
    nullterminate(string);
    if (cmd) {
        for (cp = cmd; *cp; cp++) {
            if ((*cp >= 'a') && (*cp <= 'z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((*cp >= 'A') && (*cp <= 'Z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isDecimal(*cp)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isBlank(*cp)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((*cp == '.') || (*cp == '/') || (*cp == '-') ||
                (*cp == '+') || (*cp == '=') || (*cp == '_') ||
                (*cp == ':') || (*cp == ',') || (*cp == '\'') ||
                (*cp == '"')) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    if (cmd) {
        cmdtmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
        strcpy(cmdtmp, cmd);
        tmpchar = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
        if (tmpchar == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); /* print an error message */
            return 1; /* return with failure */
        }
        strcpy(tmpchar, cmd);
        ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
        if (strstr(cmd, "|") == NULL) {         /* not a pipeline */
            makeArgs(cmd, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, 0, 0);
            for (j = 0; j < argc; j++) {
                string[0][j] = argv[j];
                structcommand[i].argv = string[0]; /*process;*/
            }
            n++;
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; *(ptr1 + i); i++) { /* tokenize the input string for each pipeline*/
                n++; /* save number of pipelines */
                int e = 0; /* a counter */
                *pString = "\0"; /* should malloc and free this? */
                strcpy(string1, *(ptr1 + i));
                if ((string1[0] != '\0') && !isspace(string1[0])) { /* this is neither the end nor a new argument */
                    ptr = str_split(pString2, *(&string1), ' '); /* split the string at the arguments */
                    h = 0;
                    for (j = 0; *(ptr + j); j++) { /* step through the arguments */
                        /* the pipeline is in cmdtmp and the argument/program is in ptr[i] */
                        if (ptr + j && !b && strstr(*(ptr + j), "'")) {
                            b = true;
                            strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j));
                            if (y < 1) {
                                y++;
                            }
                        }
                        while (b) {
                            if (*(ptr + j) && strstr(*(ptr + j), "'")) { /* end of quote */
                                b = false;
                                if (y < 1) {
                                    string[i][j] = strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j));
                                }
                                y = 0;
                            }
                            else if (*(ptr + j)) { /* read until end of quote */
                                string[i][j] = temp;
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                b = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ptr + j) {
                            if (*(ptr + j)[0] == '{') {
                                keep = true;
                            }
                            if (testFn(*(ptr + j))) { /* test for last char */
                                string[i][j - p] = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
                                keep = false;
                                free(*pString1);
                                goto mylabel;
                            }
                            if (keep) {
                                *pString1 = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
                                *pString1 = concat(*pString1, " ");
                                p++;
                            } else {
//                                strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j));
                                b1 = false;
                                int q = j;
                                for (e = 0; *(ptr + q + e); e++) { /* step through the string */
                                    b1 = true;
                                    if (*(ptr + e + q)) {
                                        *pString = concat(*pString, *(ptr + e + q));
                                        *pString = concat(*pString, " ");
                                    }
                                    j = e;
                                }
                                if (makeArgs(*pString, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, i, h)) {

                                    write_command(&w, argv, string[w]);

                                    /*for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
                                        dest = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(argv[r]) + 1);
                                        *dest = '0';
                                        strcpy(dest, argv[r]);
                                        string[w][r] = dest;
                                    }*/
                                    w++;


                                } else {
                                    if (!b1) { /* no args (?) */
                                        for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
                                            string[i][r] = argv[r];
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    mylabel:
                    free(ptr);
                    dump_argv((const char *) "d", argc, argv);
                }
            }
            free(ptr1);
            free(cmdtmp);
            free(tmpchar);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; DEBUG && string[i][j] != NULL; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) printf("\n");
                printf("p[%d][%d] %s\n", i, j, string[i][j]);
            }
            structcommand[i].argv = string[i];
        }
        fflush(NULL);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork failed");
            return -1;
        }
        /* If we are the child process, then go execute the string.*/
        if (pid == 0) {
            /* spawn(cmd);*/
            fork_pipes(n, structcommand);
        }
        /*
         * We are the parent process.
         * Wait for the child to complete.
         */
        status = 0;
        while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
        if (pid < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                    (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

            return -1;
        }
    }
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);


}
```

Comment: is `char *string[]` a mistyped `char *string[z][z]`  instance, or another variable?

Comment: No, actually, it's *not* clear what you're trying to do.  My best guess is that you're trying to make a deep copy of the given `argv` array, but in that case it's not at all clear how the variable declaration you start with, `char *string[z][z];`, fits into the picture.  It's also not clear why you appear to be freeing the allocated memory inside the function.

Comment: I was trying to refactor a large function, break out a for-loop into a function and call the function, but I'm not used to passing pointers since I'm OOP. The key insight was to understand that I don't need to pass a matrix as a parameter, passing a matrix can be done as an array. Now I try to pass a `struct` for my next refactoring and I get a similar problem because I'm not an expert C programmer.

Comment: The function `write_command` takes `int w` as first argument, but it is called with an `&w`. This won't compile, not to say segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to suppose that you are trying to make a deep copy of the `argv` array, with that being a `NULL`-terminated array of strings such as the second parameter of a C program's `main()` function.  The function you present seems to assume that you have already allocated space for the destination array itself; its job seems limited to copying the argument strings.

First things first, then: let's look at the caller.  If you're making a deep copy of a standard argument vector, then the type of the destination variable should be compatible with the type of `argv` itself (in the colloquial sense of "compatible").  If the lifetime of the copy does not need to extend past the host function's return, then a variable-length array would be a fine choice:

```
char *copy[argc + 1];
```

That relieves you of manually managing the memory of the array itself, but not of managing any memory uniquely allocated to its elements.  On the other hand, if you need the copy to survive return from the function in which it is declared, then you'll have to use manual allocation:

```
char **copy = malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(*copy));
if (!copy) /* handle allocation failure */ ;
```

Either way, you can pass the resulting array or pointer itself to your `write_command()` function, and the required parameter type is the same.  It is pointless to pass a pointer to `copy`, because that function will not modify the pointer it receives as its argument; rather, it will modify the memory to which it points.

Here is the signature of the function you seem to want:

```
void write_command(char *argv[], char *string[]) {
```

Given such a signature, you would call it as ...

```
write_command(argv, copy);
```

....

The key step you seem to want to perform in the loop inside is

```
    string[r] = strdup(argv[r]);
```

You can accomplish the same thing with a `malloc()`, initialize, `strcpy()` sequence, but that's a bit silly when `stdrup()` is ready-made for the same task.  Do not forget to check its return value, however, (or in your original code, the return value of `malloc()`) in case memory allocation fails.  Any way around, you  must *not* free the allocated memory within `write_command()`, because that leaves you with invalid pointers inside your copied array.

---

Furthermore, even if you really do have a 2D array of `char *` in the caller, such as ...

```
char *copies[n][argc + 1];
```

... *nothing changes* with function `write_command()`.  It doesn't need to know or care whether the array it's copying into is an element of a 2D array.  You simply have to call it appropriately, something like:

```
write_command(argv, copies[w]);
```

---

No matter what, you must be sure to free the copied argument strings, but only after you no longer need them.  Again, you cannot do that inside the `write_command()` function.